# Why do Dragon Ball Z episodes always stop mid-season in India?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

[*Dragon Ball Z*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragon_Ball_Z_episodes) has been telecasting on Cartoon Network India for many years. Previously, it stopped telecasting in the middle of Season 1. Then, it disappeared for years and then repeated the telecast up until the middle of the Frieza saga. The same happened with the Cell saga, up to the last run, where it stops before the Kid Buu episode.

So what is the reason for the disappearance of the show midseason every time? Why not complete the full run of a season, even when the remaining episodes are easily available on the internet?

There are some rumors that it's because of the violent content or promotion of Indian made cartoons. But I am searching for true reason behind it .

Comment: i know in america during its original run it was split up like this for translation purposes, wonder if its the same issue.

Comment: @TylerShads Indian runs of the show are previously to delayed then original. So dubbing should not be the issue but not sure if it is.

Comment: Haha! yeah! not only DBZ but also naruto and stuff..Say hi to you tube then!

Comment: I think it's a financial thing. Cartoon Network India may have decided to buy the broadcasting rights of only half seasons, which would be cheaper. IF they had to buy rights, but maybe the channel in India is not officially Cartoon Network's property. Of course this is just a speculation.

Comment: @poepje CN India is CN's official channel, so this can't be the case.

Comment: I guess this could be due less TRPs. Fans are moving to yAloutube  to avoid delays and also english dubs are not that great. People prefer English subs. Also, ads make your experience less enjoyable. This is one reason to move to youTube

Comment: When I used to Live in India, 2004-2005, they would stop the series on the episode where planet  Namek gets destroyed and restart it again, this happened till 2008. So, I Lime-wired the remaining episodes in 2005-2006. I m surprised to see they’ve  managed to get past Cell Saga.